# How can I get rid of CreationDate error from pdfx package?

Tags: xetex, latexmk, pdfx

I'm trying to compile my `memoir` document with the package `pdfx` into a **PDF/X-1a1** compliance by using XeLaTex from `latexmk` and neovim with the `vimtex` plugin.

EDIT:

Here's the following log message by compiling with xelatex:
https://pst.klgrth.io/paste/cqttj

MWE:

```
\documentclass[b6paper, 10pt, twoside, openright, final]{memoir}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.25cm}{.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout{}
\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: make a small but complete example and show it together with the log-file.

Comment: Just edited the original question.

Comment: are you redirecting files into some build folder? Is creationdate.lua written into the folder of your tex file?

Comment: 1. My build folder is mwe.  2. The file creationdate.lua is contained in the folder mwe.

Comment: well the log says that the lua is not found, so think what in your setup could prevent that (I assume that you use xelatex with --shell-escape).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I'm using xelatex but no --shell-escape option.  What does it do?  I included my latexmkrc setup in the question...

Comment: pdfx wants to call luatex to get the creation date and it needs --shell-escape for this (see the documentation, Introduction, footnote 2). (I do not think that this is a good idea from the package, --shell-escape means that the code can call external applications and that is unsecure.) you can try instead to set the date manually with `\def\pdfcreationdate{\string D:20221002224824+10'00'}` before loading  pdfx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I noticed that the creationdate.lua file is generated automatically.  Should I include that line there?  Sorry, I'm a noob on this...

Comment: no, put it in the tex file before loading pdfx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Done, now the file creationdate.lua is not created and no PDF file either.

Comment: Try without latexmk, only call xelatex. If that fails too check the log file for clues (and really the log-*file*, not some terminal output).